# How to calculate the amount of duplicates in an array in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a password validation program and 2 different error messages being exported to a .txt file then each line is converted into an array.

This is what the .txt file looks like -

```
2019-03-30 13:29:12.490929, Password < 6
2019-03-30 13:29:18.044002, Password > 14 
2019-03-30 13:42:38.230401, Password < 6
2019-03-30 13:42:40.741990, Password < 6
```

how would i add up each time "Password < 6" & "password > 14" occurs and assign them to two different variables? 
Hope i explained it well enough, appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post an example of any attempts you made to answer this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your text file with the information is called `test.txt`

```py
# extract all lines as a list
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('test.txt', 'r')]

# set two variable counters
counter_6 = 0
counter_14 = 0

for line in lines:
    # split the lines into the needed parts
    # and access only the second, password part
    password_part = line.split(", ")[1]

    # increment for Password < 6
    if "< 6" in password_part:
        counter_6 += 1
    # increment for Password > 14
    elif "> 14" in password_part:
        counter_14 += 1

print(counter_6, counter_14)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, big help!